# Angular Change Detection not triggered, parts of viewlayer not updating. ChangeDetectorRef not solving issue.

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-services, angular2-changedetection, ngzone

I have a component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../product'; // data types
import { PRODUCTS } from '../mock-products'; // database
import { CartService } from '../cart.service'; // service
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-checkout',
 templateUrl: './checkout.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./checkout.component.css']
 })


export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {

 get shoppingCart(): Product[] {
   const result = this.cartService.get();
   return result;
  }
 cartTotal: number;
 @Input() PRODUCTS: Product; 


 constructor(private cartService: CartService, private zone: NgZone, 
   private changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
     this.cartService.shoppingCart.subscribe((nextValue) => {
     this.changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
     console.log('nextValue', nextValue); // returns properly
     console.log(`subscribe: ${NgZone.isInAngularZone()}`);  // RETURNS TRUE
});

 }
 ngOnInit() {
  console.log(`ngOnInit: ${NgZone.isInAngularZone()}`); // RETURNS TRUE
  this.estimatedTotal();  // THIS FUNCTION RUNS BUT IS NEVER UPDATED WITH NEW VALUES
  }

 deleteItem(id, shoppingCart) {
  console.log('id to be deleted ' + id.toString());

   const newCart = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < shoppingCart.length; i++) {
     if (shoppingCart[i].id !== id) { 
    newCart.push(shoppingCart[i]); 
    }
  }

this.cartService.set(newCart); 
this.changeDetectionRef.detectChanges(); // THIS DOES NOT SEEM TO BE WORKING AT ALL 
}

  estimatedTotal() {
    const totals = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.shoppingCart.length; i++) { // looping through cart
        if (this.shoppingCart != null && this.shoppingCart.length > 0) {
          totals.push(this.shoppingCart[i].price * this.shoppingCart[i].quantity);
          this.cartTotal = totals.reduce((total, amount) => total + amount);
           } else {
            this.cartTotal = 0;
        }
      }
    }
```

which utilizes a service to get( ) and set( ) items to localStorage:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product'; // data model
import { PRODUCTS } from './mock-products'; // database +
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { CartItemComponent } from './cart-item/cart-item.component';
import { CheckoutComponent } from './checkout/checkout.component';

@Injectable()
export class CartService {
 shoppingCart: Subject<Object> = new ReplaySubject<Object>(1);
 constructor() { console.log(`cartService: ${NgZone.isInAngularZone()}`); }

 set(shoppingCart: Product[]) { 
  this.shoppingCart.next(shoppingCart);
  localStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(shoppingCart));

 }
 get() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
  }


  }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="pinned">
  <button (click)="checkOut()">
  <img src="./assets/icons/shoppingcart.png"/>
  </button>
</div>

<!--Modal 3-->
<div id="shoppingCart" class="modal">
<!--Modal 3 Content-->
 <div class="modal-content">
  <span class="closeModal" (click)="close()">&times;</span>
   <h3> Shopping Cart </h3>
  <table id="shoppingCartTable">
  <thead>
    <th> Item </th>
    <th> </th>
    <th> </th>
    <th> Price </th>
    <th> Quantity </th>
    <th> Total </th>
    <th> Delete? </th>
    <tr *ngFor="let cartItem of this.shoppingCart">
      <td>{{cartItem.productName}}</td>
      <td><img src={{cartItem.img}} /></td>
      <td>{{cartItem.description}}</td>
      <td>${{cartItem.price}}</td>
      <td>{{cartItem.quantity}}</td>
      <td>${{cartItem.price * cartItem.quantity}}</td>
      <td><button><img src="./assets/icons/trashcan.png" (click)="deleteItem(cartItem.id, shoppingCart)" /></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Estimated Total:</td>
      <td></td>
      <td style = "font-weight:bold">${{cartTotal}}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <button id="checkoutBtn" (click)="confirmCheckout()"> Checkout
  </button>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbodyCart"></tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

The issue I am running into, is that my UI is not updating the 
**{{cartTotal}}** when new items are added, deleted, or when localStorage (via cartService) is changed in any way. I thought it might be *a zone issue*, perhaps some changes had been processed outside the zone, and all instances of NgZone.isInAngularZone(), returned *true*. I subscribed to the cartService to see if that might solve the issue, and set off ChangeDetection, this did not give me desired results either. I then tried to enforce ChangeDetection *manually* on the subscription, this also doesn't update my **{{cartTotal}}**. I've been stuck on this for over a day, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are parts of your application using the onPush change detection strategy?

Comment: No. and parts of the view layer will update, just not {{cartTotal}}, if I refresh the page manually it updates at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You call **estimatedTotal** ing **ngOnInit**, which is only called once once the component is initialised. So it's normal that cartTotal is never updated.

You should call it whenever the cart is updated, i.e. in the subscribe method of this.cartService.shoppingCart.subscribe

```
this.cartService.shoppingCart.subscribe((nextValue) => {
     this.estimatedTotal();
}
```

Comment: this worked partially,  the value would be updated, but was always one step behind.

Answer (score 0):

David's solution worked partially, the value would be updated, but was always one step behind. I had two components with a sibling relationship that relied on one another, I ended up recombining these components as alone, they didn't have too much functionality. This resolved the problem!